# How to step into an invoked method from a DotNet DLL in dnSpy?

Tags: assembly, dll, .net, dnspy

I've been analyzing a malware written in C# using dnSpy. It loaded a dotnet assembly DLL from its Resources:
[image: the malware calling a method from loaded DLL]

I tried stepping into `InvokeMember` function, but could not go further when hitting this call:
[image]

I've dumped the DLL to file to analyze it statically, but the code is protected by SmartAssembly, so I cannot fully understand its behavior.

My question is: how can I step into the code of the method called by "InvokeMethod"? If I cannot do it directly, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution. It's simple. We only need to set a breakpoint inside the DLL.